# "Add" function in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, c89

I got declaration of linked list:

```
typedef struct element *P_element;
typedef struct element {
         char *value;
         P_element next;
} ELEM;

P_element L = NULL;
```

and I have to create function `add` with this header:

```
void Add (P_element *START_LIST, *END_LIST; char *elm)
```

But after I create code only with this code

```
typedef struct element *P_element;
typedef struct element
{
    char *value;
    P_element next;
} ELEM;

P_element L = NULL;

void Add(P_element *START_LIST, *END_LIST; char elm)
{

}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

I got error:

```
Parameter 'START_SEZ'has just a forward declaration
```

It's my first time with this error and I'm not sure, how to solve this problem. I'm even not sure, why is `P_element *START_LIST, *END_LIST;` in function header, but now I can't ask my teacher.

Answer (score 1):

i think its just a type in your declaration, no semikolon is allowd for separating paramters

try this

```
void Add(P_element *START_LIST, P_element *END_LIST, char elm)
{

}
```

Comment: 3-rd param should be `char *elem`